# Duplicate data is loading when i scroll the table list in Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi new for iOS and in my project I have added one table-list programmatically using auto-layouts, and so for everything is ok.

But when I scroll the table-list duplicate content is loading in every cell.

What did I do here wrong?(I mean first cell data is loading in all cells)

### my code:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableList = [[UITableView alloc]init];
    tableList.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    tableList.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    tableList.dataSource=self;
    tableList.delegate=self;
    tableList.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [tableList registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    [self.view addSubview:tableList];

    NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(tableList);

    NSArray * horizentalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[tableList]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

    NSArray * verticalConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[tableList]-0-|"options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

    [self.view addConstraints:horizentalConstraint];
    [self.view addConstraints:verticalConstraint];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 10;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        return 365;
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
    return 365;
    }
    else
    {
    return 50;
    }
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (Cell == nil) {

        Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    //Adding Doctor personal details on table view cell
    Personimage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    Personimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ram.jpeg"];
    Personimage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [Cell.contentView addSubview:Personimage];

    PersonName = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    PersonName.text = @"Mr.Ramakrishna";
    PersonName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:14.0];
    PersonName.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    PersonName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    PersonName.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    PersonName.numberOfLines = 0;
    [Cell.contentView addSubview:PersonName];

    Profession = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    Profession.text = @"MD (Medician)";
    Profession.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:14.0];
    Profession.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    Profession.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [Cell.contentView addSubview:Profession];

    Experience = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    Experience.text = @"Experience:12 Years";
    Experience.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:14.0];
    Experience.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    Experience.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [Cell.contentView addSubview:Experience];

    Adress = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    Adress.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Bitter-Regular" size:14.0];
    Adress.text = @"FreeDom Clinic,425 Glower Complex,NY 4582 ";
    Adress.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    Adress.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [Cell.contentView addSubview:Adress];

    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
    mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [Cell.contentView addSubview:mapView];


NSDictionary * viewsDic = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(Personimage,PersonName,Profession,Experience,Adress,bottomView,VirtualTretementButton1,VirtualTretementButton2,SendMessage1,SendMessage2,LikeButton,RefreshButton,star1,star2,star3,star4,star5,mapView);

    //Applying autolayouts for person details
    [Cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[Personimage(80)]-5-[PersonName(200)]"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:viewsDic]];

    [Cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[Personimage(80)]-5-[Profession(200)]"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:viewsDic]];

    [Cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[Personimage(80)]-5-[Experience(220)]"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:viewsDic]];

    [Cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[Adress]-10-|"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:viewsDic]];

    [Cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[Personimage(80)]"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:viewsDic]];

    [Cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-5-[PersonName(30)]-(-1)-[Profession(30)]-(-1)-[Experience(30)]-[Adress(30)]"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:viewsDic]];


 //Applying autolayouts for mapkit

        [Cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[mapView]-10-|"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:viewsDic]];

        [Cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[Adress]-10-[mapView(150)]"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:viewsDic]];
}

 if (indexPath.row == 1) {


    }

   }
```

Comment: i want solution in objective c

Comment: add create and add lable code in side the if condition.

Comment: what do you mean i am not understand and moreever i have added label code inside if condition  like([Cell.contentView addSubview:Personimage];)

Comment: You are duplicating constraints every time you dequeue a cell which is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create UILabel, UIImageview and MKMapView at runtime and during scroll and create that create each time and add in to `Cell.contentView`.

so make this in side the following if condition. Hope that will be help full for your

```
if (Cell == nil) {

        Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

Comment: i want to add that fields only in row 1

Comment: no metter but you have to put this code in side the if condition as i said

Comment: @Krish if issue is solve you have to accept answer so other aslo notice that.

Comment: cell identifier should not be unique for each cell. The whole purpose of having a cell identifier is to enable cell reusability. Having unique cell Ids defeats that purpose.

Comment: @Krish make rounded code in side cellforrowIndex Code after alloc image code. instead of viewDidAppear

Comment: some where you did wrong that have to working check what is the miscode in cellforrow. you should set rounded code for cell after allocated. and also you can use costomcell for this multiple value in cell things

Comment: Personimage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    Personimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ram.jpeg"];
    Personimage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;Personimage.layer.cornerRadius = Personimage.frame.size.width / 2;
    Personimage.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    Personimage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    Personimage.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [Cell.contentView addSubview:Personimage];  i have added like thios

Comment: try to commandt code of setting constraint then check else make uiImageview without make it globle use code like UIImageview. * Personimage =[UIiamgeview allow]init]. in side the cellfor row method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90286/discussion-between-nitin-gohel-and-krish).

Answer (score -1):

After your

```
if (Cell == nil) {
    Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

add this:

```
for (UIView *subView in cell.contentView.subviews) {
    [subView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Or assign a tag to each of the subviews that you add to the contentView and check if a view with that tag exists in the contentView before creating and adding it again.

For example:

```
if([cell.contentView viewWithTag:99]) {
    Personimage *personImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    personimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ram.jpeg"];
    personImage.tag = 99;
    personImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [cell.contentView addSubview: personImage];
} else {
    Personimage *personImage = (Personimage *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:99];
    personImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ram.jpeg"];
}
```

Comment: that remove UIView if any but OP added UILabel image and map so this for loop not helpful

Comment: you need to che is subview isKindOf Label, then remove it isKindOf UIImage then remove it isKindOF map then remove it and i think that stuff is memory consume.

Comment: All of them are subclasses of UIView so it works for everything. :)

Comment: Also memory consumption will depend on the number of subViews he has add to the contentView. It should be fine for what is added in the question.